Is Pex an acceptable pipe material for extending copper lines?
We see that our plumber installed new plastic water lines to our existing copper water lines (please see picture; connection is near floor).  1. Is it ok to connect water lines that are of different material?  2. Is it ok to use plastic as the material for water lines?  Thank you in advance

Welcome. Please take the [tour]. All you answer-commenters above really confuse the issue for new site users.

Or this? Can I Go Copper to Pex/CPVC

It is normal and okay, and you should thank your plumber for giving you a lower cost installation than copper pipe.
